# user.save() doesn't seem to save a specific field that I add to user

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I use `await user.save()` in the code below it seems to get stuck but if I use it without await it seems to move ahead and in the response the `passwordResetToken` is displayed.. However in the database, for some reason, the rest of the fields get saved but `passwordResetToken` just doesn't get saved.

I am completely lost about what the reason could be.. Any direction on what I should look for would help.

```
exports.forgotPassword = async function(req, res, next) {

  // 1. Get user based on POST email
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });

  // 2. Generate random token
  user.passwordResetToken = "123456";

  await user.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });

  // 3. Send it back as an email

  //4. Send Response
  res.status(200).json({
    status: "success",
    data: {
      user: user,
    },
  });
};
```

this is the response

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "role": "user",
            "_id": "6116aeb70aae0f7c7d8800bc",
            "name": "Jane Doe",
            "email": "jane@doe.com",
            "__v": 0,
            "passwordResetToken": "123456"
        }
    }
}
```

However the `passwordResetToken` still doesn't save it to the database although the rest of it does.. I do have the `passwordResetToken` as a field in the mongoose.Schema

I had not added this section below to my question earlier so I am adding this to help understand where the issue might lie..

This is the userModels.js

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Name is required"],
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Email is required"],
    validate: [validator.isEmail, "Please provide valid email"],
    unique: true,
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["admin", "lead-guide", "guide", "user"],
    default: "user",
  },
  photo: String,
  password: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 8,
    required: [true, "Password is required"],
    select: false,
  },
  passwordConfirm: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
      validator: function(el) {
        return el === this.password;
      },
      message:
        "Password confirmation does not match with Password. Please try again",
    },
  },
  passwordChangedAt: Date,
  passwordResetToken: String,
  passwordResetExpires: Date,
});
```

and here's the line from userRouter.js for this route..

```
router.route("/forgotPassword").post(authController.forgotPassword);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try with

```
let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });

  // 2. Generate random token
  user.passwordResetToken = "123456";

  user = await user.save();
```

or you can use

```
const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({email:req.body.email},{$set:{passwordResetToken:'123456'},{new:true})
```

new: true will return updated data.

Comment: Actually I need to run a separate instance  function userSchema.methods.createResetPasswordToken on the user and then user.save().. so find and update is not an option..

Comment: did you try storing user.save() response in user variable?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the model file contains the passwordResetToken field. Otherwise, it will be ignored.

Comment: I do have the field in the model file..:-).. and that's why it's so confusing.. I can't seem to figure out what else could be the issue..

Comment: @AlimBolar Could you add the model file code to your question? The code you've posted so far looks perfect.

Comment: I have updated the question with the models file and the routes details as well.. could you also help me figure out why `await user.save()` would make the code not work (it doesn't go ahead) while just `user.save()` at least goes ahead although it doesn't save to the database... maybe that would give us some clue to what exactly is the error..

Comment: have also updated the forgotPassword function with this part.. `await user.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });` ... the validateBeforeSave option was not there earlier .. but frankly it doesn't seem to do anything as the all validations seem to be met on save anyways..

Comment: ```userSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
  if (!this.isModified("password") || this.isNew) return next();``` I realised it was this stupid mistake I was doing.. I forgot the exclamation mark before `this.isModified`.. sorry for the bother.. and thanks for your efforts..

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the issue is with the HTTP request, you might want to have http.post  not http.put request for your posted question.

Comment: have updated the query with details about the model and the route specifications..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you find your own bug, should you delete the question or update it with an answer. But I'll just answer it here just so that someone who does the same mistake as me, can know what could go wrong.

When it seems like something is not getting saved or when you `await` the save() method and it gets deadlocked, chances are that it's the pre-save middleware..

It might not be obvious to those like me and you might end up trying to fix and replace your "perfect" code while the bug lies elsewhere..
So 2 things to check if something is not getting saved and if await creates an unending response)

**1. Check if the pre-save middleware is configured properly**

**2. Check if the middleware ends with a next()**

In my case it was this.. In the code below I had missed out the `!` before the `this.isModified("password")`
And so while testing the response would show me the right object but it would never get saved as the pre-save middleware moved to `next()`.

The `await` deadlock issue was because I did not end the middleware with the `next()` method.

this is the faulty code

```
userSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
  if (this.isModified("password") || this.isNew) return next();

  this.passwordChangedAt = Date.now() - 1000;
});
```

this is the correct code

```
userSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
  if (!this.isModified("password") || this.isNew) return next();

  this.passwordChangedAt = Date.now() - 1000;
next();
});
```

Anyways I hope this saves someone out there some time during debugging their code.